# removing last 3 characters on a file (file extension)

Tags: php

my file name are being stored in a variable **$file_name**... how can i remove the extension and just have the name only? is there something other than strcmp that i can use... that doesn't seem to do it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [pathinfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

Note: If you're not on PHP >= 5.2 use this to compose the *filename*

```
$path_parts['filename'] = substr($path_parts['basename'], 0, -1*strlen($path_parts['extension'])-1);
```

Comment: +1 for the built-in function rather than more complicated and error prone alternatives

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$file_name_no_ext = pathinfo($file_name , PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [`pathinfo()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) function.

Comment: @Salman A: Exactly what was so offensive about the link I posted? Does it really matter which mirror is linked?

Comment: @Salman: I could've done that myself. I just wanted to know *why* you thought it necessary.

Comment: There were two answers containing same link, different hostnames so I made them consistent.

Answer (score 1):

```
substr($file_name, 0, -4);
```

Comment: not really. the pathinfo solution given elsewhere on this site would return "archive.tar" in this case. Afaik there is no reliable solution to cope with double extensions ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions. [Regular expression to remove a file's extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818310/regular-expression-to-remove-a-files-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @fire, but more robust in the face of multiple dots:

```
$comps = explode('.', $filename);
unset($comps[count($comps) - 1]);
$ext = implode('.', $comps);
```

Answer (score -3):

I use:

```
$file_name = current(explode(".", $file_name));
```

Comment: So what's with file names like `foo.bar.txt`?

Comment: This will give you anything until the first `.`. What happens for `my.strange.path/i.like.dots.php`?

Comment: this will fail if the filename contains dot. Something like: this.is.a.picture.jpg