# Remove last occurrence of character

Tags: regex, r

A [question came across talkstats.com today](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/36897-regular-expressions) in which the poster wanted to remove the last period of a string using regex (not `strsplit`).  I made an attempt to do this but was unsuccessful.

```
N <- c("59.22.07", "58.01.32", "57.26.49")

#my attempts:
gsub("(!?\\.)", "", N)
gsub("([\\.]?!)", "", N)
```

How could we remove the last period in the string to get:

```
[1] "59.2207" "58.0132" "57.2649"
```

Comment: You can do it with `gsub` if you include the group at the end.  `gsub('\\.([0-9]+)$', '\\1', N)`

Comment: your first function almost works great with `sub`.

Comment: Thank you Justin but it's on the wrong end:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to remove a file's extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818310/regular-expression-to-remove-a-files-extension)

Comment: @Bohemian People who are extremely good at regex routinely have a much more liberal definition of what qualifies as a duplicate than I do. I wouldn't have the foggiest notion of how to use the answers at that question to solve this problem in R.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe this reads a little better:

```
gsub("(.*)\\.(.*)", "\\1\\2", N)
[1] "59.2207" "58.0132" "57.2649"
```

Because it is greedy, the first `(.*)` will match everything up to the last `.` and store it  in `\\1`. The second `(.*)` will match everything after the last `.` and store it in `\\2`.

It is a general answer in the sense you can replace the `\\.` with any character of your choice to remove the last occurence of that character. It is only one replacement to do!

You can even do:

```
gsub("(.*)\\.", "\\1", N)
```

Comment: Great explanantion flodel.  Thank you for the response.  I checked Rohit Jain because I think his response is more generalizable to more varied situations.  For this particular situation your response is spot on +1

Answer (score 16):

You need this regex: -

```
[.](?=[^.]*$)
```

And replace it with empty string.

So, it should be like: -

```
gsub("[.](?=[^.]*$)","",N,perl = TRUE)
```

**Explanation: -**

```
[.]         // Match a dot
(?=         // Followed by
    [^.]    // Any character that is not a dot.
     *      // with 0 or more repetition
     $      // Till the end. So, there should not be any dot after the dot we match.
)
```

So, as soon as a `dot(.)` is matched in the look-ahead, the match is failed, because, there is a `dot` somewhere after the current dot, the pattern is matching.

Comment: @Arun.. Sorry, a little misplacement of `$` was there. Fixed it now.

Comment: Once you add `perl=TRUE` that gives `[1] "59.2207" "58.0132" "57.2649"` rather than the requested result.

Comment: @Justin. Well, isn't that what is requested? I thought, OP wanted to replace just the last `period` and not the complete string following it.

Comment: @Justin.. I knew that. Cheers :)

Comment: @Arun.. I don't know about those functions and the language `r`, so I can't comment. I just posted a valid regex, that would work with your function.

Comment: I intentionally made the title say character instead of period to make this question more generalizable to others.  I believe this response is the most generalizable to multiple situations. +1

Comment: @TylerRinker: Both solutions should be equivalent. There is a small different with `.` any character **but new line** being used in flodel's solution, but it can be fixed easily.

Comment: @nhahtdh.. Thanks for pointing out the concept of `Regex-directed engines`. Didn't knew that earlier. :)

Comment: @Arun.. Sure. Will add that.

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm pretty poor with regex but this solution could be used to get rid of the last zero in the string using `gsub("[0](?=[^0]*$)", "", N , perl = TRUE)` can flodel's be extended to do the same?  Ah yes it can.  `gsub("(.*)0", "\\1", N)`  Moving the check to flodel as that is simpler.

Comment: @RohitJain: I think I removed that comment since it is not really relevant. Well, it's OK if you learn something...

Comment: @nhahtdh.. Yeah, sure. It's fine :)

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure you know this by now since you use `stringi` in your packages, but you can simply do

```
N <- c("59.22.07", "58.01.32", "57.26.49")

stringi::stri_replace_last_fixed(N, ".", "")
# [1] "59.2207" "58.0132" "57.2649"
```

Comment: **stringi**  is awesome and getting awesomer.  Thanks for adding this approach as well. +1

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty lazy with my regex, but this works:

```
gsub("(*)(.)([0-9]+$)","\\1\\3",N)
```

I tend to take the opposite approach from the standard.  Instead of replacing the '.' with a zero-length string, I just parse the two pieces that are on either side.