# Getting an src url without the file extension

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code for jQuery to get the `src` of an image `$(this).find("img").attr("src")` so, I'm sure as you all know it will return something like `http://www.mysite.com/this.image.png`

Is there any such statement that can allow me to grab the url without the file extension so: `http://www.mysite.com/this.image` so I can add some things to the url like `pview` for an image preview file or `big` for a large image etc.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use string manipulation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818310/regular-expression-to-remove-a-files-extension

Comment: `var src = "http://www.mysite.com/this.image"; src.substr(0, src.lastIndexOf("."));`

Comment: @Givi Don't forget to assign that second part into a new variable (or back into `src`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
 var img = $(this).find("img").attr("src");  
 img = img.substring(0,img.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Comment: what is error.... lemme check the method, i assume img is a string that has a value?

Comment: error says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'lastIndexOf' of undefined`. Ooooh, actually I made a mistake, I was calling `$(this)` outside of my method so it doesn't know what `this` is.

Comment: yeah, sounds like the var img didn't contain a string value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var url   = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
var parts = url.match(/(.*)\.([^\\/]+)$/);
console.log(parts[0]); # => http://www.mysite.com/this.image
console.log(parts[1]); # => png
console.log(parts[0] + '.big.' + parts[1]);
#=> http://www.mysite.com/this.image.big.png
```

**Regex Explanation:**

```
(.*)        // capture all the characters before
\.          // .. a dot character
([^\\/]+)$  // capture any characters afterwards (that are not `\` or `/`)
```

Comment: can you elaborate on your regexp please?

Comment: good answer, and I really like the idea of having an array with the substrings, but for some reason I just don't understand regexp, and I will be using the same file extensions so I went with the substring method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) tutorial for the JavaScript `substring()` function. It allows you to extract characters from a string. It should look something like this (not tested):

```
var url = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
var urlLength = url.length -4; //The -4 is for the last 4 chars. Example ".png"
url = url.substring(0, urlLength);
```

I hope this helps!