# How do I use string.replace with regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to strip the file extension from a file name using a regular expression and `String.replace`

I'm using this regex: `/^.*(\..*)/` which should capture the extension, or at least everything after a `.`

Doing `str.replace(/^.*(\..*)/,"");` just gives me a blank string.

Doing `str.replace(/^.*(\..*)/,"");` gives me `".pdf"`

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KAK82/

Comment: How many dots are there in your filenames? You could split them by dot and take the first part?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression to remove a file's extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818310/regular-expression-to-remove-a-files-extension)

Comment: @Ryan Answers to that question do not use String.replace. I want to know how to use `string.replace` with regular expressions. Stripping the file name is a problem that can be solved many different ways.

Comment: @putvande I could, but then I wouldn't be using `string.replace` with regular expressions.

Comment: Try using http://regex101.com

Comment: @Joeytje50 this appears to be just a regex tester. According to another regex tester that I use, it works in that it captures what I intend for it to capture on the types of strings I intend to use it on. I don't think this tool will help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options here:

- Only match the extension and replace it with an empty string:

  ```
  str.replace(/\.[^.]*$/, "");
  ```
- Match the entire string and capture everything but the extension, and then replace with the contents of that match:

  ```
  str.replace(/^(.*)\..*$/, "$1");
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You need to capture (with `(.*)`) the first bit of you file, not the extension itself:

```
var string = "CommercialTribe - Copy (14).pdf"
var re = /^(.*)\..*/;
console.log(string.replace(re,'$1'));

// Output: "CommercialTribe - Copy (14)"
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KAK82/1/)