# remove the character after the dot php

Tags: php

my string: 1660807356design-1.pdf

I want remove text after dot (if file pdf => remove .pdf)...

I try `trim()`, `replace()`, `substr()` but not working

```
$file = substr($items['pdf_name'], 0, -4);
```

Comment: Please DEFINE **not working** and then check this : [sandbox](https://onlinephp.io?s=s7EvyCjg5eLlUkm0VTI0MzOwMDA3NjVLSS3OTM_TNdQrSElTsgbKpmXmpCrYKhSXJhWXFGmoJOooGOgo6JpoWoP0piZn5CuAlYC59nYA&v=8.1.9)

Comment: A good answer provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818310/regular-expression-to-remove-a-files-extension

Comment: What if you have `something.nothing.interesting.pdf` as the file name?

Comment: Use [`this`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22537165/4964822) answer in the marked dupe as it seems to work [`just fine`](https://onlinephp.io/c/8b590)

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
$str = "1660807356design-1.pdf";
echo explode(".",$str)[0];
```

Comment: ``$str = "2660807356design-1.LOL.pdf";`` Output: 2660807356design-1 !!!

Comment: @OMiShah , this is a perfect K.O.