# How to replace Javascript multiline comments with text in middle using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace a two multiline comments (on a single line) with javascript text in the middle. I am using a build tool, which reads the entire file, and need to replace a specific string (made up of comments) during the build.

Example:

```
var data = /*testThisDelete:start*/new Date();/*testThisDelete:end*/
```

Once replaced, should used like this

```
var data = 4.6.88
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this to get started:

```
"your file as a string".replace(new RegExp('/\*testThisDelete\:start.*testThisDelete\:end\*/','m'), '"replacement text"');
```

See this post for a lot of useful additional info: [JavaScript replace/regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162529/javascript-replace-regex)

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for. For some reason I couldn't figure out how to escape everything. Regex drives me crazy, but I know I need to get better at it

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for:

```
^.+?(\/\*testThisDelete:start\*\/.+?\/\*testThisDelete:end\*\/)$
```

With this you should just be able to replace the first matched substring with what you want.

[image]

Comment: I tried this and it worked once I deleted the $ sign at the end and the "^.+?" at the beginning. Why is that stuff at the beginning? Excuse my lack of knowledge in Regex. I know the $ means end of line. I remember being on a site that created that image you put below, but can't remember. Could you let me know?

Comment: @Vernacchia Those indicate the beginning and end of a line. But you need to remember to pass the `m` (multiline) option at the end of your regular expression literal so that they match line breaks. (If you're new to regular expressions, you also might not know to pass the `g` option, or it only replaces the first match). Regular expressions go inside slashes `/.../` and the options go at the end: `/.../gm`