# Counting upper and lower case characters in a string

Tags: javascript, string

First off, I know this is far from professional.  I'm trying to learn how to work with strings.
What this app is supposed to do is take a simple text input and do a few things with it:

count letters, count upper and lower case letters, count words and count spaces.  Here is what I've done:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Case Check</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkCase(text)
        {   

            var counter = 0;
            var letters = 0;
            var lowercase = 0;
            var uppercase = 0;
            var spaces = 0;
            var words = 0;


            for(; counter < text.length; counter++)
            {
                if(isUpperCase(text.charAt(counter))) {uppercase ++; letters++;}
                if(isLowerCase(text.charAt(counter))) {lowercase ++; letters++;} 
                if((text.charAt(counter) == " ") && (counter < text.length))
                {
                    spaces += 1;
                    words += 1;
                }
                if((text.charAt(counter) == ".") || (text.charAt(text(counter)) == ",")) continue;
            }
            return  [letters, lowercase, uppercase, spaces, words];
        }

        function isUpperCase(character)
        {
            if(character == character.toUpperCase) return true;
            else return false;
        }

        function isLowerCase(character)
        {
            if(character == character.toLowerCase) return true;
            else return false;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var typed = prompt("Enter some words.");
        var result = checkCase(typed);
        document.write("Number of letters: " + result[0] + "br /");
        document.write("Number of lowercase letters: " + result[1] + "br /");
        document.write("Number of uppercase letters: " + result[2] + "br /");
        document.write("Number of spaces: " + result[3] + "br /");
        document.write("Number of words: " + result[4] + "br /");
    </script>
</body>
```

Made several changes due to users' suggestions. The problem now is that it won't let me treat 'text' like a string object.

Comment: Check your console. You have some syntax errors in your function that prevents it from being defined.

Comment: charAt(text(letters)) == "," seems like a typo

Comment: Apparently I'm using isUpperCase incorrectly if it is even a proper method

Comment: Created my own isUpperCase and isLowerCase functions.  Getting error that says 'text' is not a function. I assumed that when a user entered something into the prompt that it would be stored as a string object.  Is this assumption incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if whole problem, but bad paren on this one

```
if(text.charAt(letters)) == " " && text(letters) < text.length)
                       ^
```

Should be

```
if(text.charAt(letters) == " ") && text(letters) < text.length)
                              ^
```

And actually I'd make it

```
if((text.charAt(letters) == " ") && (text(letters) < text.length))
```

Comment: I'll try that and I also added 'counter' so it is text(counter) now.. small logic problem i caught that could lead to big problems

Comment: Your parenthesis idea got rid of all of the syntax errors -Thanks! But still getting Reference error on checkCase(typed).

Comment: Looked and not seeing anything obvious to my eyes. The comments on the initial question about syntax errors possibly causing it to be undefined are correct (been burned there). Also, long shot, but might try (a) Moving the def into the HTML body with the other script just for testing, and (b) commenting out all the code and you should have it defined, then introducing code a bit at a time until it becomes undefined.

Comment: some other things. isUpperCase should be isuppercase.
isLowerCase should be islowercase.
Some of your "++" are not joined with the variable, 
Like "uppercase ++" should be "uppercase++"

Answer (score 29):

Use regular expressions.

**Example**

```
var s = "thisIsAstring";
var numUpper = s.length - s.replace(/[A-Z]/g, '').length;  

// numUpper = 2
```

Se more at [JavaScript replace/regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162529/javascript-replace-regex)

Comment: or just `var numUpper = s.replace(/[^A-Z]/g, '').length;`

Answer (score 15):

You can use match() and regular expressions.

```
var str = "aBcD"; 
var numUpper = (str.match(/[A-Z]/g) || []).length;    // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`isUpperCase` and `isLowerCase` are not JavaScript functions.

You can replace them with something like

```
var isUpperCase = function(letter) {
    return letter === letter.toUpperCase();
};

var isLowerCase = function(letter) {
    return letter === letter.toLowerCase();
};
```

There were a lot of syntax errors in your code which you need to check.

I was also getting confused with all your brackets so instead of using the `charAt` I just referenced the string like an array. So instead of 
    `text.charAt(letters)`
I used 
    `text[letters]`
which I found easier to read.

See the full jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X6p5x/). I modified your code slightly because jsFiddle doesn't allow `document.write`

Comment: `text` is also a JavaScript reserved word, so you shouldn't name your variables that.

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is using `Array.from()` make an array which includes each character of `str` and then using `reduce()` to count the number of the uppercase letters.

```js
const str = 'HeLlO';
const res = Array.from(str).reduce((acc, char) => {  
  return acc += char.toUpperCase() === char;
}, 0);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the solutions here will fail when string contains UTF8 or diacritic characters. An improved version that works with all strings can be found at the turbocommons library, here:

https://github.com/edertone/TurboCommons/blob/1e230446593b13a272b1d6a2903741598bb11bf2/TurboCommons-Php/src/main/php/utils/StringUtils.php#L391

Example:

```
// Returns 2
StringUtils.countByCase('1声A字43B45-_*[]', StringUtils.FORMAT_ALL_UPPER_CASE);

// Returns 1
StringUtils.countByCase('1声A字43B45a-_*[]', StringUtils.FORMAT_ALL_LOWER_CASE);
```

More info here:

https://turbocommons.org/en/blog/2019-10-15/count-capital-letters-in-string-javascript-typescript-php

Play with it online here:

https://turbocommons.org/en/app/stringutils/count-capital-letters

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using CharCodeAt() method.

```
const bigLettersCount = (str) => {
  let result = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i += 1) {
    if (str.charCodeAt(i) > 64 && str.charCodeAt(i) <91 ) {
      result += 1;
    }
   }
   return result
  }

console.log(bigLettersCount('Enter some words.'))
```