# How to convert array of object into an array of object with different format?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm having an array of object,in which I'm storing the **billkey** and **billvalue** as attributes. I want **billkey** to be the key and **billvalue** to be the value of that particular key.

```
var log=[
{
  billkey:"Name",
  billvalue:"ABC"
},
{ 
  billkey:"Department",
  billvalue:"Computer"
}
{
  billkey:"Name",
  billvalue:"XYZ"
},
{ 
  billkey:"Department",
  billvalue:"Electrical"
}];
```

And I want to convert it into this format:

```
var log=[
    {
      Name:"ABC",
      Department:"Computer"
    },
    { 
      Name:"XYZ",
      Department:"Electrical"
    }];
```

Comment: Write custom function for this

Comment: What is the logic which says `Department` for `ABC` is `Computer`?

Comment: what language do you use. i can support you with Pyhon

Comment: @DinuDuke: Looks at the tags : `JavaScript`

Comment: i can suggest you to go with replacing the key and value  using Regx  look this link this might help you...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162529/javascript-replace-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this simple solution. Hope it helps!

```js
var log=[
{
  billkey:"Name",
  billvalue:"ABC"
},
{ 
  billkey:"Department",
  billvalue:"Computer"
},
{
  billkey:"Name",
  billvalue:"XYZ"
},
{ 
  billkey:"Department",
  billvalue:"Electrical"
}];

var arr = [];
var finalObj = [];

for(var i in log){
 var someObject = log[i];
 for(var j in someObject){
   arr.push(someObject[j]);
 }
}

for(var k = 0; k < arr.length; k+=4){
      finalObj.push({
      Name: arr[k+1],
      Department: arr[k+3]
    });
}

console.log(finalObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

create the result using forloop

```
 // store the values
  var logs=[];
  var log=[
{
  billkey:"Name",
  billvalue:"ABC"
},
{ 
  billkey:"Department",
  billvalue:"Computer"
},
{
  billkey:"Name",
  billvalue:"XYZ"
},
{ 
  billkey:"Department",
  billvalue:"Electrical"
},
];
```

loop the first array

```
for (i = 0; i < log.length; i++) {
    // create empty variable for storing the values
    var index = new Array();
    // insert the first index value to key
    index[log[i].billkey] = log[i].billvalue
    // insert the second index value to key 
    index[log[i+1].billkey] = log[i+1].billvalue
    // insert the result in to new array
    logs.push(index);
    // increment the i with 1 
    i=i+1;
}
console.log(logs);
```

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < log.length; i+=2)` would be much better.... that you can avoid `i=i+1;` ( which is equivalent to `i++;`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and use the remainder operator as witch for using either the last object or create a new one.

```js
var log = [{ billkey: "Name", billvalue: "ABC" }, { billkey: "Department",  billvalue: "Computer" }, { billkey: "Name", billvalue: "XYZ" }, { billkey: "Department", billvalue: "Electrical" }],
    result = log.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        var o = {};
        if (i % 2) {
            r[r.length - 1][a.billkey] = a.billvalue;
        } else {
            o[a.billkey] = a.billvalue;
            r.push(o);
        };
        return r;        
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```