# Replace substring in all lines in textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, textarea

Am trying to replace a particular string from all lines using javascript. Here is sample

```
 www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8IJkexsjlI&index=37&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
 www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYOQLPW6ewQ&index=38&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
 www.youtube.com/watch?v=ejRmaOHs1rk&index=39&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
```

I want to replace the 11 characters after '=' how can I do it with a variable
like  var= 'hello123456'

so output will be

```
www.youtube.com/watch?v=hello123456&index=37&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
www.youtube.com/watch?v=hello123456&index=38&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
www.youtube.com/watch?v=hello123456&index=39&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3
```

Comment: show what have u tried

Comment: Did you try to use string methods? like `replace`, `substring`?

Comment: seems like a basic regular expression

Comment: Your question is incomplete. `so output will be`??? Also you have failed to specify what is this 11 characters or after which `=`. You have also not shared any effort. You can look into `string.replace`, `string.split` and `string.substring` but please give it a try

Comment: You're being serial downvoted because you haven't shown any attempt to answer the question on your own, if you have tried, show us the non-working code, so we have a starting point on how you're trying to address this.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162529/javascript-replace-regex

Answer (score 1):

Here is regex solution, see the snippet below

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

 var link = "www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8IJkexsjlI&index=37&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3";
 var value = "hello123456";
 link = link.replace(/\?v=(.*)\&index/g, "?v="+value+"&index")
 document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = link

});
```

```html
Input link:
<div>www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8IJkexsjlI&index=37&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3</div>
<br>
<br>
Output link:
<div id="id"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward solution, without any fanciness so you could easy understand what's happening.

```
var originalStr = 'www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8IJkexsjlI&index=37&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3';
var textToReplaceWith = 'hello123456';
var newStr = '';

// get index where unwanted text starts
var index = originalStr.indexOf('v=') + 2;

newStr = originalStr.substring(0, index); //take part just before the unnecessary text
newStr += textToReplaceWith; //add string you want
newStr +=  originalStr.substring(index + 11, originalStr.length) // take text part after unwanted text
```

Comment: Regex is always better in such case. `/v=[^&]*(?=&|$)/`

Comment: @Rajesh your regex catch a whole string https://regex101.com/r/PsAdJM/1

Comment: @Rajesh - depends on how you define "better".  Personally I usually prefer to avoid regex, even if it is a slight performance hit for the simple sake of readability.  Maintaining string replacements is easier.

Comment: @user2366842 in that case, you will loop through string and find index of `v=`. Then you will take first half in temp and again loop in the remaining string for index of `&`. And finally you will do another substring on remaining string to replace value. Plus if this behavior is to be repeated multiple times, you will make it a function and call it manually. Regret takes care of all this. Yes not everyone is good in regex, but sometimes it better to add comment on such places to maintain readability. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code

```
var youstr="www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8IJkexsjlI&index=37&list=PLB03EA9545DD188C3";
var start=youstr.indexOf("=");
var end=start+11;
var replaceStr=youstr.slice(start,start+11);
youstr=youstr.replace(replaceStr,"ReplaceString");
```