# Javascript: Find all mentions in a string manipulate them and replace them

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find all `@mention` occurrences in a comment and replace them with a different format.

I have this regex that groups all occurrences, but all this point I would have to manipulate these strings for Jira (`[~string]`), and plug them back into the original string.

```
comment.match(/[ ]@[^\s]+/g);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment entered:

```
guiyjhk @test hgjhgjh test@this_is.test2 jhgjhgjh @this_is.test2
```

This is what I want to be returned:

```
guiyjhk [~test] hgjhgjh test@this_is.test2 jhgjhgjh [~this_is.test2]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript replace/regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162529/javascript-replace-regex)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can match with a regex the captures the part after the `@` and the spaces before and use `replace()` to replace those matches. This will allow you to match `@mention` surrounded by whitespace while avoiding `test@this_is.test2`

```js
let comment = "guiyjhk @test hgjhgjh test@this_is.test2 jhgjhgjh @this_is.test2"

// catch space then @ then non-space replace with space(s)[non-space]
comment = comment.replace(/([\s+])@([^\s]+)/g, "$1[~$2]");
console.log(comment)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could capture zero or more times a whitespace or assert the start of the string in group 1 , match an @ followed by capturing in a group not a whitespace `\S+`

[`(^|\s+)@(\S+)`](https://regex101.com/r/hy6QWF/1/)

Then in the replacement use group 1 and 2 `$1[~$2]`

```js
const strings = [
  "guiyjhk @test hgjhgjh test@this_is.test2 jhgjhgjh @this_is.test2",
  "@test"
];
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s.replace(/@(\S+)/g, "[~$1]"));
});
```