# How can I separate Username and ID from command?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I made a code using the DankMemer Youtube Imgen API. When I type:
`,youtube hello`
, it displays:

[image]

But when I tag someone, it displays the text along with the ID:

[image]

Is there a way I can separate the username from the text?

```js
let target = message.mentions.users.first() || message.author;
let profilepic = target.avatarURL;
let sentence =  args.join(" ");
let url = ` https://dankmemer.services/api/youtube?avatar1=${profilepic}&username1=${target.username}&text=${sentence}`;

message.channel.startTyping();

snekfetch.get(url, {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": token
  }
}).then(async res => {
  await message.channel.send({
    files: [{
      attachment: res.body,
      name: `${target.tag}-youtube.jpg`
    }]
  }).then(() => message.channel.stopTyping());
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let sentence =  args.join(" ");
```

you joined the args there which I think also includes the user mentioned. The only thing you need to do is remove the mention. If you want to remove only the first mention then do this-

```
if (!target === message.author) {
    let toremove = `{@${target.id}}`;
    sentence = sentence.replace(toremove, "");
}
```

Add this code after this line-

```
let sentence =  args.join(" ");
```

Comment: I got a idea and wrote this:
`
let sentence = args.join(" ").replace(new RegExp(${message.mentions.users.first()}), "")
`


AND IT WORKED!!

Thx for the idea

Comment: Yeah that was a great way I often mess up with regex so I didn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all mentions in the message's content with blanks [using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162529/javascript-replace-regex), like so:

```
let messageContentWithoutMentions = message.content.replace(new RegExp("<@\d+>","gm"),"")
```

If you wanted to remove something else, just make use of the [`string.replace`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function.

Comment: Maybe edit your answer to show an expected input and output? It just seemed to me that you wanted to remove mentions from a message.