# How to find and replace a series of repeated words in an array of string?

Tags: javascript

I have this array of string:

```js
let prompts = [
  "This is some word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is something else"
];
```

Is it possible to write a function that can find repetitions in the array (e.g: `This is some more word`) and replace it with "REPEATED" while keeping the first one intact. We also need the ability to set a number for the words to be considered as "repetitions" otherwise it will match pretty much everything.

When I call the function. the output will be:

```js
[
  "This is some word",
  "This is some more word",
  "REPEATED",
  "REPEATED",
  "REPEATED",
  "This is something else"
];
```

This has been troubling me for a long time before I reach out for help, because the string in the `prompts` variable is totally random and I want to eliminate repetitions in OpenAI prompts. Thus this question.

Thanks in advance!

---

Update: This is the closest I got so far

```js
function detectRepetitions(arr, minWords) {
  const uniqueWords = new Set();
  const repeatedWords = new Set();

  // Iterate over the array and find repeated words
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const words = arr[i].split(" ");

    for (let j = 0; j <= words.length - minWords; j++) {
      const subArray = words.slice(j, j + minWords);
      const subString = subArray.join(" ");

      if (uniqueWords.has(subString)) {
        repeatedWords.add(subString);
      } else {
        uniqueWords.add(subString);
      }
    }
  }

  // Replace repeated words with 'REPEATED'
  const result = arr.map((sentence) => {
    let words = sentence.split(" ");
    let repeatedFound = false;

    for (let i = 0; i <= words.length - minWords; i++) {
      const subArray = words.slice(i, i + minWords);
      const subString = subArray.join(" ");

      if (repeatedWords.has(subString)) {
        if (repeatedFound) {
          words.splice(i, minWords, "REPEATED");
        } else {
          repeatedFound = true;
        }
      }
    }

    return words.join(" ");
  });

  return result;
}

let prompt = [
  "This is some word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is something else",
];

const minWords = 4;
const result = detectRepetitions(prompt, minWords);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What effort have you made? Please share that as a text-based [mcve]

Comment: I assume the current code has been output by ChatGPT?

Comment: Yup. But that's the closest one.

Comment: It should be replaceable by regex using global replacement.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162529/javascript-replace-regex

Comment: Ask it to amend the function where it only to replaces the subsequent repeated strings, not the first.

Comment: Why are you checking the strings word by word? Wouldn't checking if the entire string is already in the array enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the initial array into a new one where you build it item by item, and if an old value is encountered again, you'd fill the new array with `'REPEATED'` instead. You can assign this new array to the old one if you want to override it.

```js
let prompts = [
    "This is some word",
    "This is some more word",
    "This is some more word",
    "This is some more word",
    "This is some more word",
    "This is something else"
];
prompts = prompts.reduce((acc, cur) => (
    acc.includes(cur) ?
        [...acc, 'REPEATED']
        :
        [...acc, cur]
), []);
console.log(prompts);
```

Comment: Thank you! `reduce()` is the answer! Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use some nested loops to achieve this:

```js
let prompts = [
  "This is some word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is something else"
];

function replaceRepeated(arr) {
  for (let i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j <i; j++){
      if(arr[i] === arr[j]){
        arr[i] = 'repeated'
      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
console.log(replaceRepeated(prompts))
```

Also here's a video I made about `for` loops in JavaScript:
[for loops in js](https://youtu.be/uXUG90OrV3Y)

Answer (score 1):

O(n) answer with hash

(Nested loops answer will be O(n^2) time complexity. i.e. poor performance for large array of strings)

This should also be faster than the reduce answer as javascript .includes() performs a linear search on the growing acc, which makes the function O(n^2) time complexity.

```
let prompts = [
  "This is some word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is some more word",
  "This is something else"
];

const make_repeated = (prompts) => {
  const hash = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < prompts.length; i++) {
    const sentence = prompts[i];
    if (hash[sentence] !== undefined) prompts[i] = 'REPEATED'; // i.e. seen before
    hash[sentence] = 0; // intialize
  }
  
  return prompts;
}

console.log(make_repeated(prompts));

// ["This is some word", "This is some more word", "REPEATED", "REPEATED", "REPEATED", "This is something else"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const usedPrompts = {}

const promptsCleaned = prompts.map((prompt) =>  {
  if (usedPrompts[prompt])  {
    return 'REPEATED'
  }
  usedPrompts[prompt] = true

  return prompt
})
```

`promptsCleaned` will hold your desired array.